# Nifi on Kubernetes local. Received invalid Secret Key for request type GET

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

[Pod Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7H9M.jpg)
Was trying to start kubernetes nifi cluster in local. Steps Followed :

1. docker pull apache/nifi
2. kubectl run my-nifi --image=apache/nifi:latest
3. kubectl port-forward my-nifi 8080:44399

44399 port on which nifi is listening on the container, found from logs.
2020-07-30 15:01:05,052 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 44399

on-loading this http://localhost:8080/ I get below error.

```
2020-07-30 15:31:48,066 ERROR [pool-2-thread-2] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Failed to process request from Bootstrap due to java.io.IOException: Received invalid Secret Key for request type GET java.io.IOException: Received invalid Secret Key for request type GET at org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener.readRequest(BootstrapListener.java:273) at org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener.access$100(BootstrapListener.java:39) at org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener$Listener$1.run(BootstrapListener.java:170) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

## The same image is running fine on docker with below command.
docker run --name nifi -p 8080:8080 -d apache/nifi:latest

Comment: seems like you service is not up - log into the pod and look at the bootstrap logs or any log of sort

Comment: Service is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nifi Image doesn't expose 44399 as the port so it shouldn't be accessible , hence you are not able to access. Image only exposes 8080, 8443, 10000, 8000 each for different purpose.
Use 8080 to access Nifi over http to access via docker.

`kubectl port-forward service/<nifi-svc-name> <local-port>:8080`

or

`kubectl port-forward pod/<nifi-pod-name> <local-port>:8080`

This will run your application locally on port local-port

Comment: This is the first thing i have done. But getting following error : E0731 01:38:13.866274   34799 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod 0f384f4c2c0fe0df31d7092a2545834efe7aedb354357564dcbb2c11af093ba8, uid : exit status 1: 2020/07/30 20:08:13 socat[41705] E connect(16, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8080, 16): Connection refused.  Control is not even reaching the nifi service if i use port 8080.

Comment: Added Pod Details to the main post for your info.